# Cant't config downloaded (zip) NDK for Android Studio (windows 7)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, android-sdk-manager

so I tried to download NDK from StandAlone SDK manager and it didn't have the option! then I went to google developers and read some guides and understood how to get it via android Studio

there was an NDK option in SDK manager -> SDK tools tab , I checked it and after applying it started downloading it, but for some reason after download, it fails to install it (tried 2 time it fails at end of unzipping process at like 100% :| ) ***Note: I have enough space available, 4gb on windows drive, 20gb on SDK drive
***Note2: I deleted the NDK bundle folder and its contents created by the failed install in my SDK folder

so I went to [NDK Download](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html)
and downloaded the package from there , but I can't get it to work, gradle says "Error:NDK not configured. 
Download it with SDK manager.)"

I tried adding the NDKfolder to PATH variable or adding NDK_HOME variable but still the same error

Update 1 : I added ANDROID_NDK_HOME variable now it says : Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':TMessagesProj'.

Comment: just download zip from [here](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html) and unzip it anywhere, more: http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/android/android_ndk.html

Comment: @pskink ty, ill check this atricle

Comment: @pskink that article, contains many steps that you need to do manually, doesn't android studio does all of it for you if it recognizes your NDK?

Comment: check your `local.properties` file, it has `sdk.dir` set already, then add `ndk.dir`

Comment: @pskink it says this at the start of the file --- ## This file is automatically generated by Android Studio.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!----

Comment: @pskink that's my question :), where can i change it in android studio

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue of

> Error:NDK not configured. Download it with SDK manager.)

But I solved my problem with this link:  [Add C and C++ to your Project](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html#download-ndk)

you can skip to the heading Download the NDK and Build Tools, but read everything for knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

This error might be, your Android Studio is not able to find the NDK location.

So, try doing this: right click on your project in Android Studio,select "Open Module Settings", select SDK location tab, and provide SDK and NDK locations.